# Reference Named Ranges from External Sheet As A Let Variable In Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel file that's grabbing data from multiple other files, leveraging their named ranges to make a data set.

At the moment, to capture the data I need from a file, I am doing something like this in a single cell using a Let statement for simplicity.

```
=Let(
    AllData,'`longLongLongFilePath[SpreadSheetName.xlsm]Sheet1'!A1:ZZ9999`
    LastRow,'`longLongLongFilePath[SpreadSheetName.xlsm]Sheet1'!namedCellWithLastRow,
    maxDate, `longLongLongFilePath[SpreadSheetName.xlsm]Sheet1'!namedCellUsedForMaxDate,
```

...bunch of filter calcs, `tocol` etc.

My goal is to simplify and not have to paste in the named range for the same filepath multiple times (in my case it would be 7 per file). So instead have something like this:

```
=Let(
    myFile,'`longLongLongFilePath[SpreadSheetName.xlsm]Sheet1'`,
    AllData,myFile!A1:ZZ9999,
    LastRow,myFile!namedCellWithLastRow,
    maxDate,myFile!namedCellUsedForMaxDate,
```

As one might guess, Excel does not recognize the concatenation or joining of these members after the `!` . I've tried a few combinations of using double quotes, `&`, and escape terms, but haven't been successful. Is there a way to set an external workbook or sheet as a let variable and then reference various named ranges from that variable?

If there's another way to do this that doesn't involve LET, that would work too. I am aware of how to do this using VBA, but I'm trying to keep this cloud-friendly.

Comment: INDIRECT would be the only way and, as you know, that comes with its own issues.

Comment: @ScottCraner Ugh... I forgot about that and I suspect that might be the presumed solution from Microsoft. I could not have that recalculating on every cell change. I wonder if I could quarantine the calc within an `if` statement. So would `indirect` get calculated in this situation: `If(FALSE,indirect(...."blah blah'),"Off")` ?  Typically no, but I'm not sure how volatile functions behave when ignored in if conditions. (I'll test later)

Comment: Vba may be a better approach if allowed

Comment: @P.b, as I said, vba isn't an option as it won't work on MS web Excel or in powerapps, etc. I could easily leverage a UDF to get this via vba.

Comment: @PgSystemTester It might be possible to use Power Query to create queries rather than named ranges. This would let you establish connections to the queries in other files and refresh your data on demand.or on open. The other possibility is Typescript instead of vba. This would be cloud friendly, at least with SharePoint.